# How do I set up second IIS website with different domain name on a single server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I've never done this before so I'm looking for help.  we have a domain, domain.com, and the default site set up in IIS with a DNS forward lookup entry to have domain.com point to the site host so we can access domain.com/application.

What my developers want is for me to set up a second site beside the default site called beta.domain.com and have a domain name entry pointing to that.  Normally this wouldn't be a problem but both the beta.domain.com site and the default domain.com site will be in IIS on the same host.  So how do I have a DNS entry point to the same host but have them point to different sites?

It may be very simple, I've just never done it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing this on a single IP address, you will need a [host header](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=WS.10).aspx).

If you are using separate IP addresses per site with both IPs assigned to the same server, you should modify the [bindings for that site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=WS.10).aspx) so that each site is bound to a different IP address.